# DB2 functions returning error SQL CODE 4743?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

I've been trying to solve this issue now for a while. I have a table called `Students` like:

```
ID     |Classes    |Priority
----------------------------
3       A51         1
3       B51         2
3       K5B         2
3       M5A         2
4       XN5         1
5       XN5         1
5       A51         2
9       BX1         1
9       BX2         2
9       AK3         2
```

I am using DBVisualizer right now to execute my statements, but I am trying to play around with something called `LISTAGG()` as a DB2 function:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    LISTAGG(classes, ',') within GROUP (ORDER BY Priority) AS GROUPED_CLASSES
FROM
    Students
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

However, every time I try to run this, I get this error:

```
1) [Code: -4743, SQL State: 56038]  ATTEMPT TO USE A FUNCTION WHEN THE APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY SETTING IS SET FOR A PREVIOUS LEVEL. SQLCODE=-4743, SQLSTATE=56038, DRIVER=4.22.29
2) [Code: -514, SQL State: 26501]  THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.22.29
```

And I have no idea how to fix it or why it is like this. I tried researching into this and someone suggested to do this:
`SET CURRENT APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY = 'V11R1'`
but there was no luck with this either, same error even though it ran.

I also tried to look at the version of my DB2 with `SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` and this returns DSN12015 (no idea what this means).

I'm desperately looking for an answer or some help, thank you very much. The goal is to have the result look something like:

```
ID    |Grouped_Classes     |
-----------------------------
3      A51, B51, K5B, M5A
4      XN5
5      XN5, A51
9      BX1, BX2, AK3
```

Comment: Disclaimer, I don't use DB2. Just found [this article](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=samples-grouping-values-by-using-listagg-function) googling, but at it does mention some requirements for using LISTAGG(), maybe it's useful? *"...1. You must activate Db2 12 for z/OS function level 501 by applying APAR PI70535.
Note: In addition to applying the APAR, you must explicitly activate the function level by issuing the ACTIVATE command. For example `-db2a ACTIVATE FUNCTION LEVEL (V12R1M501)` 2. You might also need to bind or rebind your application with V12R1M501 ...."* (cont'd)

Comment: `REBIND PACKAGE(DSNTEP3.DSNTEP3.(*)) APPLCOMPAT(V12R1M501)`

Comment: @SOS do i just run -db2a ACTIVATE FUNCTION LEVEL (V12R1M501)

Comment: Tbh I don't know.  Like I said, I don't even use DB2, just found that information by googling :-) But the article does suggest it *might* require several steps. I just found this as well, seems to be more detailed steps about applying APAR P170535 at the bottom starting with *"To activate Db2 12 function level 501, complete the following steps:...."*  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=d1fl-function-level-501-activation-enabled-by-apar-pi70535-may-2017

Comment: Let us know if you have any luck

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: @SOS honestly, i read the doc but had no luck as I don't have access to do all that :(

Comment: @Charles whatcha mean by platform? So when i ran ```SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1```, it returns ```DSN12015```, so I believe it is ibm db2 version 12?

Comment: @stackerstack platform...Z/OS, LUW, or IBM i ...

Comment: @Charles i believe it is iBM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH STUDENTS (ID, Classes, Priority) AS 
(
          SELECT 3, 'A51', 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'M5A', 2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'XN5', 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'XN5', 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'B51', 2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'K5B', 2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'A51', 2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'BX1', 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'BX2', 2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'AK3', 2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
*/
SELECT 
  ID
, SUBSTR (XMLSERIALIZE (XMLAGG (XMLTEXT (',' || CLASSES) ORDER BY PRIORITY) AS CLOB (100)), 2)
  AS GROUPED_CLASSES
FROM STUDENTS
GROUP BY ID
```

| ID | GROUPED_CLASSES |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | A51,K5B,M5A,B51 |
| 4 | XN5 |
| 5 | XN5,A51 |
| 9 | BX1,BX2,AK3 |

Comment: it's giving me an "ILLEGAL USE OF THE WORD VARCHAR" error

Comment: Seems, that Db2 for z/OS doesn't support [xml serialization](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-xmlserialize) as varchar. I've edited my answer. Try it.

Comment: Oooo, so my platform is z/OS? And when I ran that I got: ```[Code: -433, SQL State: 22001]  VALUE <XML-Value> IS TOO LONG. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.26.14```

Comment: Can you uncomment the commented out lines and run the statement as is? Do you get the same error?

Comment: Yeah i get:
```1) [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "<END-OF-STATEMENT>". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14
2) [Code: -514, SQL State: 26501]  THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.26.14```

Comment: I changed the CLOB size to 10000 as a random number and it worked, but the output under GROUPED_CLASSES just shows CLOB "X" Bytes

Comment: This means, that the statement works, but your client doesn't show CLOBs by default. Find the place in the client, where it's possible to change such a behavior. Or try to CAST the whole expression to, say, VARCHAR (10000) explicitly.

Comment: I'm using db visualizer version 12, not sure if this is what you mean by client

Comment: [5.6.12 View and edit Binary/BLOB and CLOB Data](https://www.dbvis.com/doc/12.0/12.0.pdf#page97)

Comment: I cannot find in here where it actually lets you view the output as something viewable instead of clob

Comment: In `Tools -> Tools Properties -> General -> Data Formats` below the `Presentation of Binary/BLOB and CLOB Data`. Set `Value` in the `CLOB` field.

Comment: Oh perfect it worked, the text was so small and it was hard for me to read it without zooming in and spending hours to go through it, i really appreciate it.

Comment: I've never used the XML functions before but are there any caveats to them or are they just regular functions like DATE/DATETIME?

Comment: All the functions in my example are built-in ("regular" if you like) ones. You may consider such a combination of them in the example as working alternative to `LISTAGG` which doesn't work in your environment because of unknown reason. So, if it resolves your goal, just use it then :)

Comment: Ahhh I see, and if possible, is there a way you could help me make it so that assuming each ID can take a max of 3 classes at a time, where the first class is the first_priority, and the subsequent are 2nd and 3rd priority, how could i split the string up and make columns for each of them?

Comment: Please, mark this answer as accepted, if it solves your initial problem. Then open another question with some data example similar to this one and the result desired. This one s to avoid lengthy discussion of a single solution.

Comment: Yup will do that, do you mind checking it out as well? I'll post a link here after I made it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832796/db2-split-string-into-multiple-columns i made it here